# XmlReader get element default from schema

Tags: .net, xsd, xmlreader

This is probably a naive question about `XmlReader`, but I haven't turned up an answer in the MSDN docs.

Suppose that I have XSD `SchemaTest.xsd`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="pageSettings">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="width" type="xs:decimal" default="8.5" minOccurs="0"/>
        <xs:element name="height" type="xs:decimal" default="11" minOccurs="0"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

well-formed `XML` document `SchemaTest.xml` conforming to this schema

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<pageSettings xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="SchemaTest.xsd">
  <width/>
  <height>11</height>
</pageSettings>
```

and that I try to read this document with an `XmlReader` as follows.

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
    decimal width;
    decimal height;

    XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
    settings.IgnoreWhitespace = true;
    settings.Schemas.Add(null, "C:\\Projects\\SchemaTest\\SchemaTest\\SchemaTest.xsd");
    using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create("C:\\Projects\\SchemaTest\\SchemaTest\\SchemaTest.xml", settings)) {
        reader.ReadStartElement();
        if (reader.Name == "width") {
            width = reader.ReadElementContentAsDecimal("width", "");
            // if fail, width = default from schema
        }
        if (reader.Name == "height") {
            height = reader.ReadElementContentAsDecimal("height", "");
            // if fail, height = default from schema
        }
        reader.ReadEndElement();
    }
}
```

Currently I am receiving a `System.FormatException` indicating that the content on the element `width` is not in the correct format. It appears that `reader` is trying to read the content in the element and is not defaulting to the default value specified in the schema. What is the correct way to handle this?

Further, it is my understanding that for elements, the schema only provides a default value if an element appears with empty content but that it does not provide a default value if the element is missing. Does this imply that there is no way to obtain a default value for optional elements that are missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As for working with empty elements, set `settings.ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema` and you should get the default value as desired.

Regarding missing elements, those are considered, well, missing ;-) and thus do not have a default value. Theoretically, you could parse the schema (e.g. using the Schema Object Model) to get the default value. But that would be against the spec.

Have you considered using attributes, like `<pageSettings height="55"/>`? In that scenario, you should get the default values for missing attributes.

Comment: settings.ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema did the trick. Thank you.